# Rails - Method to return if a merchant is open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Merchant model. The model accepts_nested_attributes for the Working Hour model.

Merchant Model

```
class Merchant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many   :working_hours, inverse_of: :merchant, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :working_hours, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Working Hour model

```
class WorkingHour < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :merchant 
end
```

The working_hours table has:

```
class CreateWorkingHours < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :working_hours do |t|
      t.integer :day
      t.time :open_time
      t.time :close_time
      t.references :merchant, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The merchants can have more than one working_hour block by day
 ex: 8:00 to 12:00 / 15:00 to 18:00.

I want to create a method to return if the merchant are opened or closed. How can I do that?

Comment: Find all the working hours of the vendor - get the current hour - loop through the records until you come upon the current hour being between the open and close time of a records - if you don't get a positive return - the vendor is closed (i had a wacky idea involving converting all the entries into an array of numbers that the vendor is open but that makes no sense) - quick question - day of the week doesn't matter?

Comment: Yes, the day of week is the day on integer data table (0 to 6).

I thought to do something like that, but before loop through the records until you come upon the current day of week and after the current time.

But i'm a pretty new to ROR/ruby. I'm not figured out how can i do that.

Something like 

Time.current.wday == working_hour.day 

open_time < Time.current && Time.current > close.time

Comment: Actually - I'd review the rails guide on queries [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).  Really I think you just want a simple query that checks for the vendor open on that day and if any of those records has the hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
We've should've lost the `self.` part

try to add this to your merchant model

```
def open?
    self.working_hours.any? { |wh|
        (wh.open_time.hour..wh.close_time.hour).cover?(Time.current.hour)
    }
end
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly return `true` and `false`

Comment: The Time.current does not return the Time zone? (config.time_zone is set)

Comment: Yes. 
How can I call the method in rails console to test it?

Comment: maybe `Merchant.first.open?`

Comment: I receive the following error NoMethodError: undefined method `open?' for #<Merchant:0x000000039d2f80>

Comment: @user1301037 Please check the updated answer, We should've lost the `self.` part, If it works I think the day check part would be easy, Isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124955/discussion-between-moataz-zaitoun-and-user1301037).